# Flutter Web: SPA: using URL parameters in meta data tags

Tags: html, single-page-application, flutter-web

I would like to get the parameters in a URL and use them to generate an og:image meta tag in my SPA. The specific purpose is to have a dynamic thumbnail for a given url. The idea is for crawlers to be able to find the appropriate thumbnail.

example URL:

```
https://my.app/#/post?uid=abc&pid=123
```

These two parameters will not necessarily always be included. I hope it won't cause an issue.
My understanding is that crawlers generally only check the html for metadata. How could I include a bit of code in my html before the metadata? (I am relatively new to HTML)

Would I be able to put a script in the head tag? Are variable in the script available outside of the script? Can I use variable in the URL address of my og:image tag?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://my.app/{uid}/{pid}/thumb.png" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="Get Dressed. Better than you ever had">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="vestiqweb">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>VESTIQ</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body id="app-container">

  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

  <script>
    var firebaseConfig = {
      //config info
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js?version=14" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to put a script before the meta tags and used window.location.href to get the URL. I used URLSearchParams to extract the parameters. However, I can only get the second parameter and not the first. If I add an '&' before the uid it works, but makes the url look weird... "?&uid"

```
<script>
    const queryString = window.location.href;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    const uid = urlParams.get('uid')
    const pid = urlParams.get('pid')
    if (uid != null && pid != null)
      document.getElementById('urlThumb').content = `https://my.app/posts%2F${uid}%2F${pid}%2Furl_thumb.jpg?alt=media`;
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on whether it worked and how it worked?

Comment: I replied to your comment on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364474/flutter-web-spa-open-graph-dynamically-assign-ogimage-meta-tags/63378799?noredirect=1#comment113794285_63378799

Comment: That method listed there works great. Hope that helps